# Using tinyGPS++ with millis errors

Tags: arduino-uno, gps

Hi I am trying to make search GPS (using tinGPSplus) every x time. The problem is when I do compile the code:

```
void loop()
{
    read=BP_mnger.pressedButton();
    navigateMenus(read);
    dealWithUsedEvents(getmenuUsed());
    setmenuUsed(0);


    if (isStarted && (GPSSearchPeriod<=millis()-oldMillisVallue)) {

        oldMillisVallue=millis();// if i comment this line it works
        Serial.print(F("oldMillisVallue: "));
        Serial.println(oldMillisVallue);
        while (ss.available() > 0){
            if (gps.encode(ss.read()))
                if (gps.location.isUpdated() || gps.date.isUpdated() || gps.time.isUpdated() || gps.altitude.isUpdated() || gps.satellites.isUpdated() || gps.hdop.isUpdated())
                    GPSSentence=makeGPSSentence( );
        }

    }
```

I get this:

```
oldMillisVallue: 22355
oldMillisVallue: 24356
oldMillisVallue: 26357
oldMillisVallue: 28358
oldMillisVallue: 30359
```

When I comment out:

```
oldMillisVallue=millis();// if i comment this line it works
```

I get this :

```
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
2000,0,0,4294967295,15,43,3,36,5,41,4.066298,48.269157,77,0.12,90,380,98,2,1,3
2000,0,0,4294967295,15,43,3,39,5,43,4.066298,48.269157,79,0.122200,92,380,98,2,1,3
------------------------
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0

oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
2000,0,0,4294967295,15,43,4,39,5,43,4.066265,48.269126,80,0.12,94,380,101,3,2,5
2000,0,0,4294967295,15,43,4,41,5,45,4.066265,48.269127,82,0.121900,94,380,103,3,2,5
------------------------
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
oldMillisVallue: 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only reading from the serial port every `GPSSearchPeriod` milliseconds. That gives plenty of time for the small serial read buffer to overflow and lose the data.

Instead you should be reading *all the time* regardless of your desire to only do things periodically. Sure, *report* the data periodically, but you *must* read all the time *as well*.

Comment: Just to be sure you are talking about the Serial buffer ? 
"reading all the time" wouldn't that drain the battery ? my goal was like to make one GPS search each 2 seconde to save battery

Comment: The SoftwareSerial buffer, yes. Unless you are sleeping the MCU reading all the time will make no difference. You are just looking at the content of the serial buffer.

Comment: thank you very much, now i can read properly the data. 
last question i tried putting the while (ss.available() > 0) with declaration of the gps in a function that i call every time as u said to save sram (the SoftwareSerial is still global) i had no output is it because the decalring the gps as local variable ?

Comment: Yes. You need the gps instance to either be global or local and `static` - the effect is the same (just the scope is different).